# Testing synchronized method/blocks in spring

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have the following method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Ticket buyTicketFor(String user) {
    Ticket ticket = null;

    synchronized (MUTEX) {
        List<Ticket> availableTickets = ticketRepo.findAllTickets();
        Collections.shuffle(availableTickets);
        ticket = availableTickets.get(0);
    }

    return ticket;
}
```

I want to create a test that allows me to test two users getting two tickets, but they must not access the DB at the same time. How can i create a test to allow me to do this. I wanted to use mockito and junit 5, but im thinking that it will only be possible using integration testing, where i spin up an actual server and DB.

Comment: Check out https://www.testcontainers.org/they have hooks for spring boot, or you can statistically spin it up and hook it into the spring context via an ApplicationContextInitalizer

Comment: This won't work in an environment with multiple instances of the application. Use the database instead (isolation level serializable and obtain a pessimistic lock) of you want to have a better solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is just a test application, there wont be multiple instances. But being able to hit the application using multiple threads? is what im thinking... unless anyone has any good ideas how to test this kind of scenario

Comment: Write a multi threaded test. You don't need a database for that.

Comment: I guess you want to use mockito to mock the `ticketRepo`. Not sure whether you really need to test the `synchronized` as its a java mechanism. What is MUTEX excactly (I would assume a simple Object thats only used for locking)? Note that your code will fail if there are no tickets available.